# how to have multiple NICs in pc without using USB to Ethernet adapter

Tags: linux, networking

so i have linux pc and 8 port unmanaged switch , is there a way that i make the pc every port in the swwitch as NIC , i saw there is a way by installing NIC server , or using USB to Ethernet adapter , any help guys will be appreciated, if you are wondering what im trying to do is im planing to buy multiple APs and i want to bind them to gns3

Answer (score 0):

If you have free pci slots in the pc you can get expansion cards. You can even get quad port cards